# Pointer of byte array

Tags: pointers, vb6, casting

So, I'm basically looking to know how to turn this

```
BYTE *b
func(b);
```

into VB6 when b is a dynamic array that has already been redim'ed. Would it be

```
func(b)
```

or

```
func(VarPtr(b))
```

Thanks, iDomo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both, really.

But the easy way is `func(b)`, where `func` is something like `func(b() as byte)`. The `b` array is then passed by reference.

Comment: What if the function's parameter needed to be a pointer to the array of bytes, in Long form?

Comment: @iDomo Is the function a native VB function, or is it `Declare`d?

Comment: It's a native C compiled function.
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (hProcess As Integer, lpBaseAddress As Long, lpBuffer As Long, nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Integer

Comment: @iDomo Then you shoud have phrased your question in a completely different way, as both the current question and answer have no relation to what you actually need. The function would be `Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Long, ByRef lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long`, and you would pass `b(lbound(b))` for the third param. The function will receive the pointer to the first byte of the array. Do not omit `ByVal`s, they are important.